# How to get a QuerySet with a range of "Created in the Last Five Minutes" according to the database clock

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get a Django QuerySet that gives me objects created in the last five minutes according to the database clock.  Presumably I want some type of __range thing, but I can't seem to work out the right Django magic to give me a range of "now" to "now minus 5 minutes".

Any pointers to the documentation would be appreciated

Comment: Don't you just want "is greater than (now - 5 minutes)"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
five_minutes_ago = django.utils.timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=-5)
fil = MyModel.objects.filter(req_time__gte=five_minutes_ago)
```

Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do something like this, as already mentioned by @DanielRoseman in comments

```
Model.objects.filter(created__gte=now()-5_MINUTES)
```

Assuming your model haves created field (for that you can have a look here https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#timestampedmodel)

And please check the value of 5_MINUTES constant too

**Reference** : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#gte

Comment: But isn't that now() returning time relative to the Python clock rather than the database clock?  I'm not particularly fussed about down to the second accuracy, but I do have some concerns that timezone and other idiocies will cause issues.

Comment: I think that's same time that will be stored in created field while creating model, would you mind explaining what do you mean by database time ?

Comment: I was under the impression that Django used the underlying PostgreSQL timestamp type rather than using its own time.  Apparently that is not the case.

Comment: Um, what do you expect me to do in response to "someone-answers"?